# The write() method of a SocketChannel do not throw an exception when it should do

Tags: java, exception, socketchannel

I'm writing a server to exchange messages among clients. One issue left to be solved is how to release a channel when a client happens to be closed. What I do is to start a monitor thread in which the all-Clients map is monitored, and I attempt to remove() a channel if an exception been detected when trying write() to it. However, after closing a client, the write() method in monitor thread don't throw an exception so the useless channel will never be released. Anybody know why?

```
public class ServerMonitor extends Thread{
private Map<String, SocketChannel> allClients;
private Set set;
private Iterator it;
private Entry entry;
private SocketChannel channel;
private ByteBuffer buf;

public ServerMonitor(Map<String, SocketChannel> allClients) {
    this.allClients = allClients;
    buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10);
    byte b = 0;
    buf.put(b);
    buf.flip();
}

public void run(){
    while(true) {
        if(!allClients.isEmpty()) {
            set = allClients.entrySet();
            it = set.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                entry = (Entry) it.next();
                channel = (SocketChannel) entry.getValue();
                try{
                    channel.write(buf);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    allClients.remove(entry.getKey());
                    //set.remove(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `this.allClients = allClients;` <-- this is pretty dangerous unless you really know what you are doing... If the caller modifies the map, your class' map will see the changes! Good source for `ConcurrentModificationException`s...

Comment: @fge I do want to perform this.allClients = allClients; because I need to modify the source allClients (release a useless channel) when the monitor thread has detected a channel which cannot be written bytes to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a TCP socket is buffered locally and put on the wire asynchronously. So you can't rely on the first write after the peer closes to fail. You can rely on a subsequent write failing, but it could take a number of writes to get there.

Comment: So can I write bytebuffer.size() bytes to the channel so that I can detect exception in the first write?

Comment: I've just answered that. No. ByteBuffer.size() has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is the size depends on TCP itself?

Comment: What size are you talking about?

Comment: You said I can't rely on the first time of write() to handle the IOExeption because bytes are written into a buffer but not immediately into the client. So I guess maybe there is a size in the buffer so that when the buffer has 'size' bytes then bytes will be delivered.

Comment: I can only repeat. You can't get an error on the first write. Period. There needs to have been a prior write that has caused an error to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue when writing applications that send data over TCP. You've discovered that the only real way to know if a client has closed the connection is by the `IOException` on a call to `write(...)`. This is pretty much the way it works.

There is a cleaner solution. First of all, you must always handle the case that a client disconnects without you knowing, and properly remove them when you get the `IOException` on `write(...)`. However, if the client sends a message telling the server it is disconnecting, you can use that to close the connection when you see it.

Comment: Yea I really do as you say but a call to write(...) don't cause an IOException, this confuses me.

Comment: Like EJP has said, you can not rely on a particular write failing, but it will fail eventually. The more data you write to the socket, the faster it will fail.